# question about fractions and {num}{den}

Tags: texstudio

If you use $\frac{num}{den}$ the cursor jumps to {num} and you can start typing but then you have to arrow key over to {den} (hitting tab doesn't go there) and delete the letters "den" which is quite tedious. Is there any other way of doing this?
Thanks

Comment: CTRL+right arrow

Comment: you are asking about some editor but have not said what editor you are asking about. LaTeX itself has no "cursor"

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sorry, I thought this was a Texstudio forum.

Comment: @polyn thanks alt + right arrow does it, though you still have to delete the three letters 'den'.

Comment: @Rolomoto They are selected and don't need to be deleted. You can overwrite them without having to do anything special.